# Compare current date to a certain point of time (weekday, hh:mm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I'm facing the following issue: I have to compare the current Date to a certain point of time, given a weekday and the time, somehow like this:

```
const myObj = {
  "weekday": "Tuesday",
  "timeOfDay": "10:30"
}
```

The weekday is solved with Date.now().getDay() and an array of weekdays, but can't get through the time part. It shouldn't be an exact match rather an interval of ± 20 mins.

Comment: I suggest you to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). The library exists for backend and frontend.

Comment: I'd like to avoid momentjs (any frameworks for this task), because I feel a bit of an overkill to use a whole framework for a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting `myObj.timeOfDay` and the current time to minutes and checking if the absolute value of the difference is lesser than or equal to 20, e.g.:

```
var weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var now = new Date();

if (myObj.weekday === weekdays[now.getDay()]) {
  var time = myObj.timeOfDay.split(':');

  var minutes    = Number(time[0]) * 60 + Number(time[1]);
  var nowMinutes = now.getHours()  * 60 + now.getMinutes();

  console.log(Math.abs(nowMinutes - minutes) <= 20);
} else {
  console.log(myObj.weekday, '!==', weekdays[now.getDay()]);
}
```

Note, `Number()` accepts any number of leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's the 20min window that's causing the issue?

```
var timeSplit = myObj.timeOfDay.split(':');
var totalMins = parseInt(timeSplit[0]) * 60 + parseInt(timeSplit[1]);

if(Math.abs(totalMins - (Date.now().getHours() * 60 + Date.now().getMinutes())) < 21) {
    // got a hit...
}
```

EDIT: This will get a bit sketchy around midnight...